# How to Add Inner Squares to Bar Chart Using BarChart[] Function?

Tags: graphics, charts, plot-themes

I need to create a couple of bar charts, and I'm using the [BarChart](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html) built-in function.
[image]

Currently, I have managed to make them look like the image on the left.

```
BarChart[Range[5], BarSpacing -> None, AspectRatio -> {1, 1}]
```

However, I would like to add the inner squares to each bar on the chart (as shown in the image on the right), and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Any ideas? I would like to avoid using another function if possible.

Comment: How would you like the result look like when input is `data` where `SeedRandom[3];
data = RandomReal[10, 5];`?

Comment: From now I'm just working in discrete values.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. ChartElementFunction

We can use a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) to add lines to rectangles:

```
ClearAll[cEF]
cEF = Module[{xr = #[[1]]}, 
 {ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##], 
  Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Black, Thickness[Small], Opacity[0.67]], 
  If[#[[2, 2]] > 0, Map[Line[Thread[{xr, #}]] &]@Most@Range[#[[2, 2]]], {}]}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
dt1 = Range[5];

BarChart[dt1, AspectRatio -> 1,  BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[7];

dt2 = RandomInteger[12, 7];

BarChart[dt2, AspectRatio -> 1,  BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cEF]
```

[image]

#### 2.  ChartElements

```
BarChart[Range[5], 
 ChartElements -> 
    Graphics[Rectangle[], PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> None], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 BarSpacing -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to make the adjacent edges truly overlap with each other? Please note that some of them appear slightly thicker. At this scale, it may be barely noticeable, but if you, for instance, add the option ImageSize -> 800, you will observe that there is still a slight gap between each square. Furthermore, at very small scales like 80, it seems that the squares don't have the same size.

Comment: @DanielCheca, unfortunately i don't know a way to make rectangle _truly overlap_ using the option `ChartElements`. It may be easier to add the desired line using a custom `ChartElementFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; 

addLines = ReplaceAll[r: Rectangle[a_, b_, __] :> 
 {r, First @ 
  ToElementMesh[Rectangle[a, b], 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}]["Wireframe"]}]
```

***Examples:***

```
dt1 = Range[5];

BarChart[Range[5], DisplayFunction -> addLines, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, BarSpacing -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[7];

dt2 = RandomInteger[12, 7];

BarChart[dt2, DisplayFunction -> addLines, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, BarSpacing -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]